# Varnish: How to send user agent as info to wordpress for 404 monitoring

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, user-agent, varnish

I'm trying to find out all those bots who are just doing key word harvesting and (for me) useless SEO selling - like MJ12bot or AhrefsBot. My site is something like 24 years old, most of time under Wordpress, but I tried mediawiki at some point etc so I'll get a lot of 404s.

I have Apache-Varnish-Wordpress stack and I'm using Varnish to stop unwanted bots. The bot.vlc is like this:

```
sub bad_bot_detection {

if (
  req.http.user-agent ~ "Daum"
  || req.http.user-agent ~ "MJ12bot"
...
) {
    return(synth(403, "Forbidden Bots"));
} elseif (
    req.http.user-agent ~ "APIs-Google"
    || req.http.user-agent ~ "Mediapartners-Google"
...
) {return(pipe);
} else {
    unset req.http.User-Agent;
    }
}
```

At the backend/wordpress 404 monitoring is done by Rank Math SEO plugin. I'm using return(pipe); for "good bots" just getting User Agent. Otherwise I don't know when I should fix 404 and when just not care of. Humans aren't an issue because if they get 404 then there is a referer. So, I would like to find out user agent of bots that I could offer to them nice error 403.

I googled a alot and all hits of varnish and user agent are type how to serve different cache to mobiles or tips why vary: user agent is bad for caching ratio. Some articles adviced to use log of Apache2 but it didn't help too much because of unset req.http.User-Agent; in default.vcl. I know all those but I'm trying just pass the name of user agent to 404 monitoring without telling it to varnish.

Maybe I should use logging of Varnish but I couldn't find user agents from there either.

So, should I just learn to live with a lot of 404s or copy&paste all those "bad bot lists"? Can I use Varnish for hunting name of bots giving 404's at all?

EDIT: there is a language barrier (it was muvh easier if you would learn some finnish ;) ) so let's look some screenshots.

This is what I get:
[when Varnish cleans up user agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXkl0.png)

This is what I need, but without separate "cache buckets" per user agent:
[showing user agents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/peDEt.png)

(EDIT &) CLOSING (for now anyway)

It is impossible send user-agent to backend apps like Wordpress without using return(pipe); witch is quite bad idea with Varnish.

Using return(pass); doesn't work either because it just doesn't use cache but will do anything else like removing vary:user-agent - anyway, even it would work it's bad idea just sending user-agent to 404 monitor, though.

That is a bit frustrating actually. 404s by useless bots don't need any fixing but googlebot/bingbot/etc needs and now I can't know who is who. So I did a bad-bot.vcl to stop known bad/seo-harvesters and let google/bing/etc go through Varnish using return(pipe) so I get theirs user-agent to 404 monitor. I may (or may not) loose some SEO now because of a little bit slower loading times but that isn't bigger problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you return pipe from that moment on Varnish won't see anything else of the piped transaction.
try to return pass instead and using varnishlog check 404 responses.

i.e. varnishlog -d -q "RespStatus > 400" | grep "user-agent"

Comment: I'll give a try. But return(pass) just doesn't cache but will normalize headers etc. and then unset req.http.User-Agent kicks in - or am I wrong?

And there is the point of easiest way too ;) If I have user aggent info in 404 monitoring it is much easier to do redirections than greping them from varnishlogs. Sure, if varnishlog is the only option then I heve to use it - or following only te most important ones as is when a human gets 404.

Comment: And after my first mornig coffee... I'm just piping allowed good bots, nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite easy.

1. Normalize or not at Varnish, but don't `unset req.http.User-Agent`
2. Use this:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
    
    if (beresp.http.Vary ~ "User-Agent") {
        set beresp.http.Vary = regsuball(beresp.http.Vary, ",? *User-Agent *", "");
        set beresp.http.Vary = regsub(beresp.http.Vary, "^, *", "");
        if (beresp.http.Vary == "") {
            unset beresp.http.Vary;
        }
    }
}
```

Now Varnish won't cache using User-Agent (by Age and cache hits) and the backend, here WordPress, gets User-Agent. Now it is much easier to see right away if 404 cames from real user/bot.

And normalizing user-agent makes reading easier, but that is totally different story.